# How can I use C++ 20 in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: ide, c++20, visual-studio-2022, rider, unreal-engine5

I changed the CppStandard option, but the compiler keeps failing to recognize the C++20 feature and getting an error.
I tried with Visual studio 2022 and Rider IDE, and both IDE showed errors.
No relevant options were found in the compiler's project settings.
How can I use the C++20 feature on Unreal Engine 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a compiler installed that supports C++20. Also, you likely need to rerun the setup.bat and regenerate project files after a visual studio version change.